# React.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript and react, and I have been following a tutorial on how to create an e-commerce website, but I'm having an issue getting my product page to load. My original ProductListScreen.js had worked fine, but I wanted to update my project to React Router 6, and now the page won't load. I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` error, and when I checked to see on what line the error is occurring it says that the problem is on line 105, which is where `<tbody>` is. I'm unsure of why I am getting this error as I have only updated my code. I would really appreciate any help or guidance as to why I might be getting this error.
Thank you!

Updated ProductListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  createProduct,
  deleteProduct,
  listProducts,
} from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {
  PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export default function ProductListScreen(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { pageNumber = 1 } = useParams();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const sellerMode = pathname.indexOf('/seller') >= 0;
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products, page, pages } = productList;

  const productCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    product: createdProduct,
  } = productCreate;

  const productDelete = useSelector((state) => state.productDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = productDelete;
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (successCreate) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET });
      navigate(`/product/${createdProduct._id}/edit`);
    }
    if (successDelete) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET });
    }
    dispatch(
      listProducts({ seller: sellerMode ? userInfo._id : '', pageNumber })
    );
  }, [
    createdProduct,
    dispatch,
    navigate,
    sellerMode,
    successCreate,
    successDelete,
    userInfo._id,
    pageNumber,
  ]);

  const deleteHandler = (product) => {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
      dispatch(deleteProduct(product._id));
    }
  };
  const createHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createProduct());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <button type="button" className="primary" onClick={createHandler}>
          Create Product
        </button>
      </div>

      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}

      {loadingCreate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorCreate && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorCreate}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          <table className="table">
          
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            {products.map((product) => (
              <tr key={product._id}>
                <td>{product._id}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() =>
                      props.history.push(`/product/${product._id}/edit`)
                    }
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(product)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
          </table>
          
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Original ProductListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
    createProduct,
    deleteProduct,
    listProducts,
  } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {
    PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET,
    PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET,
  } from '../constants/productConstants';

export default function ProductListScreen(props) {
  const sellerMode = props.match.path.indexOf('/seller') >= 0;
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;
  const productCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    product: createdProduct,
  } = productCreate;
  const productDelete = useSelector((state) => state.productDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = productDelete;
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (successCreate) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET });
        props.history.push(`/product/${createdProduct._id}/edit`);
      }
    if (successDelete) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET });
      }
      dispatch(listProducts({ seller: sellerMode ? userInfo._id : '' }));
    }, [
      createdProduct,
      dispatch,
      props.history,
      sellerMode,
      successCreate,
      successDelete,
      userInfo._id,
    ]);

const deleteHandler = (product) => {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
    dispatch(deleteProduct(product._id));
  }
  };
  const createHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createProduct());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <button type="button" className="primary" onClick={createHandler}>
          Create Product
        </button>
      </div>
      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}
      {loadingCreate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorCreate && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorCreate}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <tr key={product._id}>
                <td>{product._id}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() =>
                      props.history.push(`/product/${product._id}/edit`)
                    }
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(product)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error here:

```
{products.map((product) => (
            //... your code ...// 
))}
```

because, during the initial render `products` is `undefined`.

Solution:

```
 {products && products.length && products.map((product) => (
         //... your code ...//
 ))}
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried ```{products && products.length && products.map((product) => (```, but my page is only displaying the info in the ```<thead></thead>``` (so the headers) not my product information ````<tr key={product._id}> <td>{product._id}</td>  <td>{product.name}</td>...```

Comment: That means your product list is not set correctly. Try console.log in your code to check whether the product list is set correctly or not

Comment: So tried console.log(productList), and I got ```{loading: true, products: Array(0)}
loading: true products: Array(0)``` and  ```{loading: false, products: undefined}
loading: false products: undefined``` in my console, but when I go into Network in my ```products?seller=&name=&category=&slug=``` the preview and response show all of my products.

Answer (score 0):

before you *map*, you should check undefined:

```
{products?.map((product) => ... )}
```